# If I delete image A in MS Azure, will image B in the shared image gallery still work if it was based on A?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

To clarify in case the wording is unclear:

1. Create image A from a VM
2. Use image A to create image B in the shared images gallery (SIG)
3. Delete image A
4. Will image B still work?

Another way to phrase it is: do the images in the SIG require their source images to be maintained or can they be deleted? Are the images in the SIG pulling info from the source images or are they images themselves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the source managed image since you create Azure VM from the **image version** in the shared images gallery (SIG) not directly from your source image.

However, you cannot update replication to another target region for your existing image version as it relies on the source image.
So, if you want to remove the source image, you'd better replicate the image to all the target regions where you want in the image version before you remove it or you could make a new image as the source image from existing VM at any time.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can now replicate to other regions after the source has been deleted.

Comment: true, you can replicate to other regions also if the source has been deleted

Answer (score 0):

As @Gunny has commented before, you can replicate to other regions also if the source has been deleted